# WPF: Remove dotted border around focused ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, focus, border

When my application change state to normal i want to set focus over my `ListView`:

```
private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        ListViewUsers.Focus();
}
```

I am doind that in order to use `Up & Down` arrows `Keys` to navigate my `ListViewItem` instead of click on my `ListView` first to set focus.

So this works fine except the fact that i have this dotted border around my `ListView`.

I try to add this line to my `ListViewItem Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"> 
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/> ....
```

But unfortunately i still see this dotted `border`.

Any seggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me.

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

How you apply style? Are you sure that `ListView` items use this style?